# Посоветуйте date-picker для Vue

Tags: vue.js

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, date-picker для Vue, что-то вроде друпдауна с опциями:

- Custom (обычный датапикер range)
- Last month
- Last Year
- This Year
- This Month
- Last 30 days and etc.

Comment: тут смотрели https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#official-resources

Answer (score 0):

Есть примеры и плагины, можно установить нужный к себе в проект, то есть готовое решение:)
https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/calendar/

Мне такой понравился https://ly525.github.io/material-vue-daterange-picker/examples.html#basic-usage